# Some boot-up services

Tags: boot, virtualbox, 16.04, apache2, mysql

I am trying to increase my boot-up speed on my 16.4 Ubuntu and would like to consult someone if removing some boot-up services is a smart idea, for i am unsure if there are consequences i am not aware of.

`virtualbox` - i think i don't need it on start up because i don't use it every session, but i am unsure if turning it off would cause errors. I use virtual boxes of linux distros that connect to the internet in various ways, ex. whonix

`apache2` and `mysql` - also dont use them always but am afraid it would make unexpected behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly disable apache and MySQL services on boot. They won't make a huge difference, but unless you are using them, they don't necessarily need to be running. Also, disabling virtualbox should not cause any errors.